# Use the value of an Observable and return the Observable again

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using an Observable to show/hide a component and want to use the data. I don't want to directly call the service in the child component so that I can keep that component dumb.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
     <child-component *ngIf="this.shouldShowChildComponent$ | async" [someData$]="data$">
     </child-component>
  `
}) export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  shouldShowChildComponent$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  data$: new Observable();

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.someService.getData().subscribe(() => {
      this.shouldShowChildComponent$.next(true);
    }
    // it looks like this is a second subscription?
    this.data$ = this.someService.getData();
  }
}
```

What happens is that it only shows the data in the child component on the second time that `this.someService.getData()` emits.

I have tried using the pipe operator in conjunction with the tap operator:

```js
this.data$ = this.someService.getData().pipe(tap(() => {
  this.shouldShowChildComponent$.next(true);
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it seems I can use [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) for that:

```js
  shouldShowOtherComponent$ = new Observable(); // changed this to an Observable
  data$: new Observable();

  // left out for brevity

  this.data$ = this.someService.getData().pipe(shareReplay(1));
  this.shouldShowOtherComponent$ = this.data$.pipe(mapTo(true));
```